# Derived set of a set in an infinite space with co-finite topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set with the co-finite topology.

Now let $A$ be a subset of $X$.

We need to find the derived set of $A$.

I have found out that the closure of $A$ will be $A$ if $A$ is finite and it will be $X$ if $A$ is infinite.
I also know that the closure of $A$ is union of $A$ and its derived set.
But I am not able to find the derived set of $A$ here.

Please help

Comment: what do you mean by "derived set"? Is this the set of limit points?

Comment: @William If course, that's the standard meaning (since Cantor introduced it for subsets of $\Bbb R$).

Answer (score 1):

$A'$, the derived set of $A$, is just the set of cluster (accumulation) points of $A$. If $A$ is finite, it has no cluster points, so $A'=\varnothing$: for each $x\in X$, $\{x\}\cup(X\setminus A)$ is an open nbhd of $x$ that contains no point of $A$ different from $x$. If $A$ is infinite, what points of $X$ are cluster points of $A$? Knowing what $\operatorname{cl}A$ is should make it fairly easy to answer that.